# Can't mass-assign protected attributes:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mass-assignment

Have tried the solutions for this common error in stackoverflow but none of them seem to work in this case, it might be that I already created an address field on the property before. I keep getting the mass assignment error.

Any help appreciated.

Address.rb

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :addressable_id, :addressable_type, :city, :county, :postcode, :street1,    :street2

  belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Property.rb

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :name, :addresses_attributes
  belongs_to :user 

  has_one :address, :as => :addressable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address

  validates :name, presence: true,  length: { maximum: 200 }
  validates :address, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

end
```

Property Controller

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy


  def index
    @property= Property.all
  end


  def create
    @property = current_user.properties.build(params[:property])
    if @property.save
      flash[:success] = " Property Added"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def new
    @property = Property.new  
    @property.build_address
  end
```

Comment: Mass-assignment error for what? Can you show the error message?

Comment: Sorry here it is ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error at /properties
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: addresses

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
```

and change

```
attr_accessible  :name, :address_attributes
```

and if it doesn't work change both `address` to `addressable`